# Specific node in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I just want to get the last child nodes `date` and `time` in a XML-File if the node `alarm` with value `true` is encountered:

XML looks so:

```
<USER>
    <date>09.07.2013</date>
    <time>08:28</time>
    <alarm>true</alarm>
</USER>
<USER>
    <date>09.07.2013</date>
    <time>08:23</time>
</USER>
<USER>
    <date>09.07.2013</date>
    <time>08:17</time>
    <alarm>true</alarm>
</USER>
<USER>
    <date>09.07.2013</date>
    <time>08:15</time>
</USER>
```

My code is:

```
        string URL = "http://IP";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "PW");

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream());
            XDocument temp = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);

            var date = temp.Element("USER").Descendants("date").Select(node => node.Value.ToString()).First();
            var time = temp.Element("USER").Descendants("time").Select(node => node.Value.ToString()).First();
        }
```

As I said before I just want to retrieve `date` and `time` if

```
<alarm>true</alarm>
```

was encountered.

Comment: they are not attribute, they are child nodes by your description of file...

Comment: @ilansch: Sorry you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more direct alternative is to use more old school XPath, with [XPathSelectElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) to find the last USER with `alarm = true`, like so:

```
 var lastUser = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//USER[alarm='true']")
                    .LastOrDefault();
 var lastUserDate = lastUser.Element("date").Value;
 var lastUserTime = lastUser.Element("time").Value;
```

AFAIK this is more or less equivalent to the Linq:

```
 var lastUser = xdoc.Descendants("USER")
                    .LastOrDefault(u => u.Element("alarm") != null 
                                     && u.Element("alarm").Value == "true");
 var lastUserDate = lastUser.Element("date").Value;
 var lastUserTime = lastUser.Element("time").Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following query to get date and time of last user element:

```
var lastUser = temp.Elements("User").LastOrDefault();
var date = (string)lastUser.Element("date");
var time = (string)lastUser.Element("time");
var isAlarm = (bool?)lastUser.Element("alarm");
```

---

UPDATE here is query which will get `DateTime` value and value of alarm from all users:

```
var users = from u in temp.Descendants("USER")
            let time = (string)u.Element("time")
            let date = (string)u.Element("date")
            select new {
                Date = DateTime.ParseExact(date + time, "MM.dd.yyyyHH:mm", null),
                IsAlarm = (bool?)u.Element("alarm") ?? false
            };
```

You will be able to get date of last user, user with max date, or filter users by alarm value. E.g. getting time of last alarm:

```
var user = users.Where(u => u.IsAlarm).OrderBy(u => u.Date).LastOrDefault();
if (user != null)
    date = user.Date;
```

Comment: You're right but same probleme, the code will retrieve with or without the <alarm>true</alarm>. I just want to retrieve if alarm true is present.

Comment: @user2428412 added code to check if `alarm` set to true. BTW your xml should have single root node

Comment: And now if the child node look so <alarm>triggered</alarm>?

Comment: @user2428412 in your xml there is `true` value for alarm nodes. Can you specify what exactly you have and what you are trying to get? DateTime of last user element with alarm equal to `true`?

Comment: Yes.. but there is an nda of what is really the alarm nodes :/

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last node with this code:

```
var lastNode = doc.Root.Elements().Where(p => p.Name == "USER" && p.Elements().Any(o => o.Name == "alarm" && o.Value == "true")).Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

```
var yourUser = temp.Root.Elements("USER").LastOrDefault(u => 
    u.Elements("alarm").Any(a => a.Value == true));

if (yourUser != null)
{
   var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
       (string)yourUser.Element("date") + (string)yourUser.Element("time"),
       "dd.MM.yyyyHH:mm");
}
```

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for. Going to try thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Use XElement instead of XDocument so you can loop all elements and attributes of your xml content

`XElement temp = XElement.Load(xmlReader);`

After that, just do so:

```
foreach (XElement user in temp.Elements("USER"))
{
    var alarm = user.Element("alarm");

    if (alarm != null && alarm.Value == "true")
    {
        var date = user.Elements("date").Last().Value;
        var time = user.Elements("time").Last().Value;
    }
}
```